# forbidden from or forbidden to

Tags: prepositions

In this sentence:

> We are forbidden a) to smoke in the classroom *or* b) from smoking in the classroom.

Which sounds better? I know that these two options are correct, however I’m thinking which one is more common and natural to you?

My British colleague told me "to smoke" is a better option, sounds more natural, what do you think about it?

Comment: Smoking in the classroom is forbidden. "Forbidden from smoking" sounds right to me, but "we are forbidden to smoke" sounds weird.

Answer (score 4):

Yes; [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/forbid), for instance, licenses both 'forbidden to' and 'forbidden from':

> **forbid** [verb; transitive] ...
>
> to order someone not to do something, or to say that something must
> not happen:
>
> - [ + to do something]: *I forbid you to see that boy again.*
> - [often passive, + from + doing something]: *He is forbidden from leaving the country.*

However, 'It is forbidden from smoking in the staffroom' sounds ghastly. [Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+forbidden+to%2Cit+is+forbidden+from&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show that 'it is forbidden to' is the overwhelmingly more idiomatic choice.  Also, the [Google 4-grams for 'we are forbidden to', 'we are forbidden from'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+are+forbidden+to%2Cwe+are+forbidden+from&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show that the former is by far the more idiomatic choice:

[image]

I personally would avoid 'forbidden from'.

Answer (score 4):

Opinions differ:

> **FORBID, PROHIBIT**
>
> These verbs are near synonyms, but they take different prepositions.
> Use *to* rather than *from* with *forbid*, and *from* rather than *to*
> with *prohibit*. Take care to avoid sentences like *They were
> forbidden from using cameras* and *They were prohibited to use
> cameras*. Make it *forbidden to use* or *prohibited from using*.
> [Lester Kaufman and Jane Straus; *The Blue Book of Grammar and
> Punctuation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qSEnEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA112&dq=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq-LOk1c2EAxXjEFkFHTroBsAQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&f=false) (2021)

> **forbid someone to do something** (not *from doing*)
>
> ***needs checking*** — The witnesses were forbidden from leaving the scene of the crime until the police had completed their preliminary
> investigation.
>
> ***revised*** —  The witnesses were forbidden to leave the scene of the crime until the police had completed their preliminary investigation.
> [Corey Frost, Karen Weingarten et al.; *The Broadview Guide to Grammar,
> Usage, and Punctuation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lor2EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq-LOk1c2EAxXjEFkFHTroBsAQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&f=false) (2024)

> **FORBID**
>
> • The verbs "forbid" is used as follows"
> • "Forbid doing sth"
> -- School authorities **forbid *bringing*** food to cafeteria.
> • "Forbid smo from doing sth"
> -- School authorities **forbid** the students ***from bringing*** food to cafeteria.
> • "Be forbidden to do sth"
> -- It **is forbidden *to bring*** food to cafeteria.
> -- Bringing food to cafeteria **is forbidden** by school authorities.
> • "Be forbidden ***from*** doing sth"
> -- Students **are forbidden *from bringing*** food to cafeteria.
> [Ulku Kucukakin; *Complete English Grammar For Exam Purposes: Summary &
> Practice Tests*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jnU8EAAAQBAJ&pg=PT131&dq=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq-LOk1c2EAxXjEFkFHTroBsAQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&f=false) (2021)

> **forbid, prohibit.** The words have the same meaning, but the
> construction of sentences often dictates which should be used. In
> prepositional constructions, *forbid* may be followed only by *to* ("I
> forbid you to go"). *Prohibit* may not be followed by *to* but only by
> *from* ("He was prohibited from going") or by an object noun ("The law prohibits the construction of houses without planning consent"). Thus
> the following is wrong: "They are forbidden from uttering any public
> comments" *(New York Times)*. Make it either "They are prohibited from
> uttering..." or "They are forbidden to utter..." A small additional
> point is that *forbid*'s past-tense form, *forbade*, has the preferred
> pronunciation "for-bad," not "for-bade."
> [Bill Bryson; *Bryson's
> Dictionary of Troublesome Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nRduHUeIzvAC&pg=PA80&dq=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq-LOk1c2EAxXjEFkFHTroBsAQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22forbidden%20to%22%20%22forbidden%20from%22%20grammar&f=false) (2004)

Comment: They were prohibited to use cameras? I'd say: from using cameras, myself.

Comment: @Lambie It says to avoid sentences like "They were prohibited to use cameras."

Comment: Sorry, but it also says to avoid: they were forbidden from using cameras.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, and the other grammar OKs "Students are forbidden from bringing food to cafeteria." I've learned that I'm evidently confused myself, but didn't realize it until now :) Perhaps what's "acceptable" is changing, or maybe it was never written in stone.